# Why does the ks.test function give a p-value of 0 for these two samples?

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have two numeric data vectors: `NA_Sales` and `EU_Sales`, which are really similar.
When I plot their ECDFs like this:

```
plot(ecdf(dataset$NA_Sales))
lines(ecdf(dataset$EU_Sales), col="red")
```

Then I get this diagram:

[image]

Which shows they are really similar. But when I run the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test like this:

```
ks.test(dataset$NA_Sales,dataset$EU_Sales)
```

or

```
ks.test(dataset$NA_Sales,dataset$EU_Sales)$p
```

Then I get a p-value equal to zero. Why? The diagram shows they are similar distributions.
Isn't `ks.test()` supposed to tell this by their CDF? I should get a p-value higher than 0.05.

Comment: With any consistent hypothesis test, very small p-values occur with small effect sizes when sample sizes are sufficiently large. They *don't* answer the question "are these similar?". In particular, with the KS test any small difference will be significant at a large enough sample size. Start with the discussion under this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349618/ks-test-always-significant and discussion on the same issue in the one sample KS test here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74434/kolmogorov-smirnov-test-strange-output

Comment: For an explanation of this issue with hypothesis tests in general see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/are-large-data-sets-inappropriate-for-hypothesis-testing and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125750/sample-size-too-large; note, for example that the 5% critical value for the two-sample test is $1.36\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}$ (&the critical value grows very slowly in $1/α$); as $\min(n_1,n_2)$ increases, that critical value gets smaller and smaller, so for a specific distance between your samples, the same test statistic will give smaller and smaller p-values

Comment: You may also get some value from this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136999/when-kl-divergence-and-ks-test-will-show-inconsistent-results/348273#348273 since the first two paragraphs apply equally here, and from some of the answers here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82579/which-to-believe-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-or-q-q-plot (even though that relates to the one sample test, the issues are again the same)

Comment: These plots are *greatly* different, but your mode of displaying them hides the differences.  Draw a [P-P plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93P_plot) instead.

Comment: whuber is quite right -- the differences are considerably more substantial than they look in this plot -- the upper quantiles in first variable are typically about 50% larger than in the second, the medians are even more different, while the lower quartiles are both 0). But even if they were much more alike, at n1=n2=16598 even quite small differences in cdf would be significant. You should note two things  that make the KS-test p-value calculation problematic - these data are *paired*, and they have a lot of zeros and quite a lot of tied small values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us show both the issue that whuber raised (that the difference is large, not small) and the one I raised (that very small differences will be significant) in one figure -- by the simple expedient of using a monotonic transformation of the data to tame the long right tail.

In this case, the transformation $g(x) = x/(1+x)$ will pull all of the data into $[0,1)$, while leaving the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance unchanged - as any transformation that is strictly monotonic in the range of the data would do.

[image: Plot of transformed ecdf for both data sets with maximum KS distance (0.21358) marked in]

With 16598 data points, this size of difference is far into the extreme upper tail. The tiny 5% critical distance marked on the plot is that under the assumptions of the test (so it's for continuous data).

The size of the critical distance grows very slowly in $1/\alpha$; if I have calculated it correctly, just doubling the size of that small critical difference would correspond to a significance level of less that $10^{-5}$ for continuous data.

However, because these data are discrete, that's highly conservative (i.e. actually corresponds to a much lower significance level); because of that any calculated p-values are considerably too large.

Note also that these data are paired; that also violates the independence assumption of the test (indeed a plot shows they're substantially correlated). Because of that and the discreteness issue, you really can't put any weight on the actual numeric p-value given by the test -- it's not a meaningful number here.

Further, these are data over time in a changing market; the values within each variable represent a mixture of different distributions, and they are also not going to be independent of each other. The value in trying to use a formal test in this way is highly dubious.