# KS-Test and KL-divergence have diffrent result

Tags: python, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, kullback-leibler

It is a similar question to this but it didn't help me [When KL Divergence and KS test will show inconsistent results?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136999/when-kl-divergence-and-ks-test-will-show-inconsistent-results)
I have run into a situation in which I have no clue how to interpret it. I tried to make it reproducible by everyone without having much to set up.

I have to compare a sample set A to some sample set B which I get from a neuronal net (it's NIM-VM). First I perform a KS-Test and then the KL-divergence. For the KS-Test I set alpha to 5%. If my p-value is lower the 0.05 I reject the hypothesis that the sample sets are form the same distribution otherwise I don't know if they are. If I reject the hypothesis I expect a higher KL-divergence, then if I couldn’t reject. To run the KL-divergence I have to make sure that my samples will sum up to 1 which brings me into problems. The closest I could reproduce the problem is with this python code:

```py
from scipy.special import kl_div
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
a = 1.45 #alpha
b = 3.56 #beta
n = (10000,1) #anzahl an exemplaren
sampleA = np.random.beta(a, b, size=n)
sampleB= np.random.beta(1.44, 3.58, size=n)
sampleC= np.random.beta(1.46, 3.54, size=n)
np.sum(kl_div(sampleA.flatten(), sampleB.flatten()))
#-> 1438.068287468729
np.sum(kl_div(sampleA.flatten(), sampleC.flatten()))
#-> 1412.757784459684
np.sum(kl_div(sampleA/np.sum(sampleA), sampleB/np.sum(sampleB)))
#-> 0.49756693113078326
np.sum(kl_div(sampleA/np.sum(sampleA), sampleC/np.sum(sampleC)))
#-> 0.4887308929567761
ks_2samp(sampleA.flatten(), sampleB.flatten())
#-> KstestResult(statistic=0.0086, pvalue=0.8533882178607826)
ks_2samp(sampleA.flatten(), sampleC.flatten())
#-> KstestResult(statistic=0.0201, pvalue=0.03518876957795689)
```

So, I reject Sample C although it has a better KL-value. I had to rerun the code multiple times to get this specific result.

Maybe a Picture of the problem will help more.

[image: Problem as picture]

The question is should I transform the data so that the sum is one like this:

```py
np.sum(kl_div( sampleA/np.sum(sampleA), sampleB/np.sum(sampleB) ))
```

or should I just do it without it, even if it won't be a pdf anymore?

```py
np.sum(kl_div( sampleA/np.sum(sampleA), sampleB/np.sum(sampleB) ))
```

In the case of calculating the sum - how can I interpret it?

Comment: What is the variable `tmp` you are normalizing `sampleA` with, and why do you expect that it will have a value such that `sampleA` will actually be normalized (correctly)?

Comment: I forgot to change it. tmp should be sampleA. I have sample values of a distribution. I thought that if I divide every value with the sum of all values I get a pdf that i can use to calculate KL @jbowman